# Accessing XAMPP/MySQL through SSH

Tags: mysql

I'm working from a Mac OSx Lion that is running XAMPP on localhost. I've been trying to find a way to run MySQL through the terminal. Normally I would do `mysql -u [username] -p` but the command is not recognized.

Am I doomed to use PHPMyAdmin for local development?

I couldn't find anything related to this on the web, hopefully someone can give me a hand.

Gracias!

Comment: is mysql installed and running without errors? do you have permissions on running mysql?

Comment: @GeoPhoenix Yes, I can use phpMyAdmin perfectly and all the applications connected to MySQL work fine. My terminal just says that the `mysql` command is not recognized.

Comment: Not much of Mac user, but usually when the "command not found" appears and mysql is installed , means that might need some adminstrative rights to access via terminal

Comment: @GeoPhoenix well XAMPP is a cross-OS package, it's meant for development and doesn't run as a server. This might be the problem, since it's not running at a global level. But either way, where could I take a look at the permissions for MySQL.

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354046/how-can-i-access-the-mysql-command-line-tool-when-using-xampp-in-os-x